# Inconsistent accessibility: property type in class is less accessible than property type in Interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, enums

Not sure what's wrong here but I am trying to use an enum in an interface I've created.

When I attempt to implement the interface I get the error

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' is less accessible than property 'BusinessEntities.ICloneMessage.AgentAddresses'

**Enum**

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public class AddressTypeValues
    {
        [DataContract(Name = "AddressType")]
        public enum AddressType
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "Home")]
            Home,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Mailing")]
            Mailing,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Location")]
            Location,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Other")]
            Other
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public interface IAgentAddress
    {
        AddressTypeValues.AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
        String? Street1 { get; set; }
        String? Street2 { get; set; }
        String? Street3 { get; set; }
        String? City { get; set; }
        String? State { get; set; }
        String? ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Classes using AddresType**

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CloneMessage : ICloneMessage
    {
        [DataMember]
        public AgentTransmission AgentInformation { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public IList<AgentAddress> AgentAddresses { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public IList<RelationshipCode> RelationshipCodes { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string? ErrorMessages { get; set; }
        public CloneMessage(){}
    }
}
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AgentAddress : IAgentAddress
    {
        [DataMember]
        public AddressTypeValues.AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Street3 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class `AgentAddress` is probably `internal`, make it a public class

Comment: If I do that I'm told I cannot have nullable `string` properties in the `IAgentAddress` interface.

Comment: `String` is a nullable class already.  You can't have a `Nullable<String>`.  Remove the question marks.

Comment: @Neal, that is completely different error, `string` is already a nullable, it is a reference type, Remove `?` with `String?`. `Nullable<T>` is used for value types, **not reference types**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your code.

First. Your class `AgentAddress` is not marked as `public`. That is why you are getting the error. Probably your class is not defined with any access specifier and it is considered as `internal`. Making your class `public` would remove the error.

Second problem in your code is that you are using `String?`. May be trying to make string as [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). **String is already a reference type, it can hold null.** You need to remove `?` with `String?`. So your interface would look like:

```
public interface IAgentAddress
{
    AddressTypeValues.AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
    String Street1 { get; set; }
    String Street2 { get; set; }
    String Street3 { get; set; }
    String City { get; set; }
    String State { get; set; }
    String ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

`Nullable<T>` or type with `?` is used for value types, since value types can't hold `null` like `int?` or `Nullable<int>`